# Inheritance from a Template Class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a template class,in fsm.h file 
and derived class in derivata.h file;
the compiler throws errors:

```
derivata.h: In constructor ‘deri::deri()’:
derivata.h:46: error: no matching function for call to ‘fsm<pin_steps>::fsm()’
fsm.h:30: note: candidates are: fsm<step_type>::fsm(step_type) [with step_type = pin_steps]
fsm.h:12: note:                 fsm<pin_steps>::fsm(const fsm<pin_steps>&)
```

fsm.h:

```
#ifndef FSM_H_
#define FSM_H_


template<class step_type> class fsm {
    protected:
        step_type   step;
        step_type   step_old;
        step_type   step_tmp;
        bool        step_pulse;
        char        name[256];
    public:
        fsm(step_type);
        void set_name(char *parent, char *myname);
        void test();
        virtual void update(){cout << "base\n";};
        void show(){cout << step << ' ' << step_tmp << '\n'; };
        void init(step_type st_current) {step = st_current;};
        //virtual ~fsm();
};

//constructor
template <class step_type> fsm<step_type>::fsm(step_type) {
    step = step_old = step_tmp = (step_type)0 ;
    step_pulse = false;
}

template <class step_type> void fsm<step_type>::set_name(char *parent, char *myname) {
    sprintf(name, "%s.%s", parent, myname);
}

template <class step_type> void fsm<step_type>::test() {
    if (step != step_old) {
        step_pulse = true;
        step_tmp = step_old;
    } else step_pulse = false;
    step_old = step;
}

#endif /* FSM_H_ */
```

and a derived class from template class:

```
#include "fsm.h"
#ifndef DERIVATA_H_
#define DERIVATA_H_

enum taglio_steps {
    ST_TAGLIO_CHECK_MOTORE,
    ST_TAGLIO_ZERO_MOTORE,
    ST_TAGLIO_WAIT_ZERO_MOTORE
};

enum pin_steps {
    ST_PIN_BOOT,
    ST_PIN_RETURN
};

class deri : public fsm<pin_steps>{
    private:
        bool    cmd_prelevamento_done;
        bool    cmd_scorrimento_done;
        float   posizione_pinza_i;
        float   posizione_pinza_f;
    public:
        deri(){
            cmd_prelevamento_done = false;
            cmd_scorrimento_done = false;
            posizione_pinza_i = 0;
            posizione_pinza_f = 0;
        };
        void update(){cout << "deri\n";};
//      virtual ~deri();
};

#endif /* DERIVATA_H_ */
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you reduce this to a [testcase](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base class doesn't have a non-parameter constructor, but in your derived class you are calling one (it is called automatically).

Change this:

```
    deri(){
        cmd_prelevamento_done = false;
        cmd_scorrimento_done = false;
        posizione_pinza_i = 0;
        posizione_pinza_f = 0;
    };
```

To this (pseudocode, I am not sure about correct syntax, I do not use this too often):

```
    deri(): fsm<pin_steps>(ST_PIN_BOOT) {
        cmd_prelevamento_done = false;
        cmd_scorrimento_done = false;
        posizione_pinza_i = 0;
        posizione_pinza_f = 0;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The base class doesn't have a default constructor which is needed if (in constructor of a derived class) you don't specify which one should be called. If you dont' want `fsm` to be default-constructible, do this instead:

```
deri() : fsm(ST_PIN_BOOT) // call fsm::fsm(pin_steps)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error seems pretty clear. You are not calling the `fsm<>` constructor, and there are no default constructors for `fsm`. Your options are thus:

- Create a default constructor: `fsm::fsm() { ... }`
- Or, more likely in your case: call the constructor in the `deri` initalization list, like this:

  ```
  deri() : fsm(step_type_here)
  {
      cmd_prelevamento_done = false;
      cmd_scorrimento_done = false;
      posizione_pinza_i = 0;
      posizione_pinza_f = 0;
  };
  ```

I would also recommend putting the other member variable initializations in the initializer list too.

Comment: `steptype` won't work there.

Comment: Obviously it's a placeholder; I don't know what the OP wants there

Answer (score 0):

That code is too big but i think you need a default constructor in the base class. Looks like Something like this

```
   public: 
    fsm(); //added
    fsm(step_type);
    void set_name(char *parent, char *myname);
    void test();
    virtual void update(){cout << "base\n";};
    void show(){cout << step << ' ' << step_tmp << '\n'; };
    void init(step_type st_current) {step = st_current;};
    //virtual ~fsm();
```